# Reading in from file with modern c++ - data is not stored

Tags: c++11, templates

maybe I get something wrong with shared_pointers or there is some basic shortcoming of mine but I couldn't get this right. So I want to read in some data from a file. There are position and momentum data on each line of the data file and the first line stores the number of data points.

I need to read this in to my data structure and for some reason my graph would not fill, although the data reads in correctly.

```
const int dim = 3; // dimension of problem

template <typename T, typename G>
// T is the type of the inputted locations and G is the type of the 
// distance between them
// for example: int point with float/double distance
struct Node{

    std::pair< std::array<T, dim>,std::pair< std::array<T, dim>, G > > pos; // position
    std::pair< std::array<T, dim>,std::pair< std::array<T, dim>, G > > mom; // momentum
    // a pair indexed by a position in space and has a pair of position
    // and the distance between these points

};

template <typename T, typename G>
struct Graph{

    int numOfNodes;
    std::vector< Node<T,G> > nodes;

};
```

This is the data structure and here's my read function (`std::cout`-s are only for testing):

```
template <typename T, typename G>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, std::shared_ptr< Graph<T,G> >& graph){

    is >> graph->numOfNodes; // there's the number of nodes on the first line of the data file
    std::cout << graph->numOfNodes << "\n";

    for(int k=0; k<graph->numOfNodes; k++){

        Node<T,G> temp;

        for(auto i : temp.pos.first){
            is >> i;
            std::cout << i << "\t";
        }

        std::cout << "\t";

        for(auto i : temp.mom.first){
            is >> i;
            std::cout << i << "\t";
        }

        std::cout << "\n";

        graph->nodes.push_back(temp);

    }

    return is;

 }
```

I have an output function as well. So if I output the graph which I intended to fill during read-in is zeroed out. Number of nodes os correct however positions and momente are all zeroed out. What did I do wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(auto i : temp.pos.first){
    is >> i;
    std::cout << i << "\t";
}
```

Think of this as similar to a function. If you have something like:

```
void doX(int i) { i = 42; }
int main() {
    int j=5;
    doX(j);
    return j;
}
```

Running this code, you'll see the program returns the value 5. This is because the function `doX` takes `i` by value; it basically takes a copy of the variable.

If you replace `doX`'s signature with

```
void doX(int &i)
```

and run the code, you'll see it returns 42. This is because the function is now taking the argument by reference, and so can modify it.

Your loops will behave similarly. As you have it now, they take a copy of the values in the arrays in turn, but are not by reference.

As with the function, you can change your loops to look like

```
for(auto &i : temp.pos.first){
    is >> i;
    std::cout << i << "\t";
}
```

This should then let you change the values stored in the arrays.

Comment: Wow man. Thanks a lot. I didn't know that for loops behave like this. Amazing. Thanks again. Now this works flawlessly.